# shorten the repetitive lines of code

Tags: loops, for-loop, recursion, scheme, racket

I am using temp to keep values in search-list for temporary, starting from biggest number of temp (temp-5) to smallest number of temp (temp-1). I want to add this function in undo function of search-list. How do I shorten the lines of codes as a loop if I use up to temp-100 instead of temp-1 to temp-5? where do I put cond if i use "for loop"?

```
#lang racket
(define temp-flag 0)
(define temp-1 '())
(define temp-2 '())
(define temp-3 '())
(define temp-4 '())
(define temp-5 '())
(define search-list '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10))
(define (place-temp tf)
  (cond
    [(equal? tf 1)
     (set! temp-1 search-list)
     (set! temp-flag 5)]
    [(equal? tf 2)
     (set! temp-2 search-list)
     (set! temp-flag 1)]
    [(equal? tf 3)
     (set! temp-3 search-list) (set! temp-flag 2)]
    [(equal? tf 4)
     (set! temp-4 search-list) (set! temp-flag 3)]
    [(set! temp-5 search-list) (set! temp-flag 4)]
    ))  

 (place-temp temp-flag)
```

Comment: Just put the temporary lists in a vector, and use `tf` as an index.

Comment: What is the larger goal, that place-temp needs to solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic solution to your problem is what Michael Vehrs suggests. The first (*least invasive*) try might be like this:

```
    (define temp-flag 0)
    (define search-list '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10))

    (define *num-of-temps* 5) ;; you will just have to change it to 100
    (define *temps* (make-vector *num-of-temps* '()))

    (define (next-temp-flag tf)
      (cond ((= tf 1) *num-of-temps*)
        ((and (> tf 1) (< tf *num-of-temps*)) (- tf 1))
        (else (- *num-of-temps* 1))))

    (define (place-temp tf)
      (vector-set! *temps* (- tf 1) search-list)
      (set! temp-flag (next-temp-flag tf)))
```

From the point of view of temp-flag it works exactly the same. But it's not a cool program, so let's try to improve it.

First of all, this *next-temp-flag* is a bit weird, but it precisely mimicks the behaviour of your cond statement with respect to *tf* and *temp-flag*.
I assume you are using *temp-flag* only for indexing *temp-1*, *temp-2*, etc., and that you don't care that much about *tf* larger than 5 (or 100, or in general than **num-of-temps**). So the first thing you can simplify it a bit:

```
    (define (next-temp-flag tf)
      (if (= tf 1) *num-of-temps* (- tf 1)))
```

Now the second thing is that positions (''indexes'') in vectors (cf https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/vectors.html) start from 0, not 1, so e.g. your *temp-1* is now *(vector-ref *temps* 0)*. So you can use ''decreased *tf*s'' like this:

```
    (define (next-temp-flag tf)
      (if (= tf 0) (- *num-of-temps* 1) (- tf 1)))

    (define (place-temp tf)
      (vector-set! *temps* tf search-list)
      (set! temp-flag (next-temp-flag tf)))
```

Obviously (or not ;)) this *next-temp-flag* can be now expressed with the modulo function:

```
    (define (next-temp-flag tf) (modulo (- tf 1) *num-of-temps*))
```

...and if you want a shorter code you can equally well inline it in *place-temp*.

The last thing are naming conventions: perhaps you have just used these *define*s to set up a minimal example, but if you actually have these ''global variables'' in your project, the naming convention is to use stars, so you'd rather use **search-list** and **temp-flag**.
Notice also that *place-temp* is causing a side effect, so you might want to call it *place-temp!*. And if you plan to apply *place-temp!* to **temp-flag** only, you can drop the argument entirely. And probably **temp-position** might sound easier than **temp-flag**, because it is a position now.
So to sum up, you might end with something like this:

```
    (define *num-of-temps* 5) ;; you will just have to change it to 100
    (define *temps* (make-vector *num-of-temps* '()))

    (define *temp-position* (- *num-of-temps* 1)) ;; because (modulo -1 n) is n-1.
    (define *search-list* '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10))

    (define (place-temp!)
      (vector-set! *temps* *temp-position* *search-list*)
      (set! *temp-position* (modulo (- *temp-position* 1) *num-of-temps*)))

    (place-temp!)
```

Sorry it's such a long answer, but as the poet said ''I didn't have enough time to write a shorter one''. I also suspect that if you want to implement undo, you probably want something else (a stack instead of a circular buffer) -- but that goes way beyond your question.

Good luck with your project!

PS I hope as you get used to scheme, you will rely less on global variables and procedures, and more on local bindings and functions (as another poet said ''stay functional my friend!''). But things take time, and the most important is that you enjoy your hacking.